# How can I pass parameters from view input to asp mvc method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have such code for sending to order my ware. My link in browser look's like this : `http://localhost:22764/Admin/AddToOrder?OrderId=1&WareId=1&WareCount=456` But when i try to go there, i get "Server error in /", 404 could not found resource. My view looks like this:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.WareId }) %> |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.WareId })%> |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.WareId })%> ||||||
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Click Me", "AddToOrder", new { OrderId = 1, WareId = item.WareId, WareCount = item.Quantity })%>

            </td>

            <td>
                <%: item.WareName %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: String.Format("{0:F}", item.WareCost) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.Quantity %>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <% } %>
```

And controller method:

```
 [HttpGet]

        public ActionResult AddToOrder(int OrderId, int WareId, string WareCount)
        {
            OrderRecord or = new OrderRecord();
            or.OrderId = OrderId;
            or.WareId = WareId;
            or.WareCount = WareCount;
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.AddToOrderRecords(or);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, ex);
            }
            return View(or);
        }
```

I think that it is routing trouble? Help me please.

route is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Proekt
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your routes.

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: What is the name of the class holding the `AddToOrder` action method?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you've shown. Is this action method within an admin controller? Do the other links work? You redirect to an index action. Does this controller have an index action?

Comment: yes it have, i do this from index

Comment: Have you built code since adding this method? What you have should work.

Comment: have you tried stepping through your get action? does it reach that far or is the error being produced before ? P.s your orderID is always set to 1. Could this be causing some sort of save exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the route debugger to find out whether the default route can catch url. install route debugger via nugget and you can try ViewBag for passing parameters.